# How do you import CSV data from a website into google sheets using ImportXML formula or similar?

Tags: web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-formula

I've imported figures before from the website socialblade.com using `=IMPORTXML(J1,"//*[@id='afd-header-views-30d']")`. But now I'd like to import a string of numbers for past month views, and I don't know how, this is what the source code of the website looks like:

```
<div id="AverageViewsPerMonth" style = "width: 860px; height: 160px; padding-top: 10px;"></div>
   <script type="text/javascript">                
   g = new Dygraph(

   // containing div
   document.getElementById('AverageViewsPerMonth'),
   // CSV or path to a CSV file.
   "Date,Monthly Views\n" + "2016-10-1,6338035\n" + "2016-11-1,3005749\n" + "2016-12-1,2951816\n" + "2017-01-1,3185303\n" + "2017-02-1,3849745\n" + , {
   title: 'Total Views Per Month for Peaceful Cuisine ',
```

Here's a Google spreadsheet anyone can edit:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DjZbiUy6P2L2i2INoN1c0tAZsAeCBmM3-PSXp9E0JFw/edit?usp=sharing

Would really appreciate if someone could show me how with a socialblade link example like this one:

https://socialblade.com/youtube/user/ryoya1983/monthly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript elements are not possible to scrape by Google Sheets

[image: 0]

---

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(TEXTJOIN(, 1, QUERY(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(IMPORTDATA(
 "https://socialblade.com/youtube/user/ryoya1983/monthly"), 5000, 3), 
 "where Col1 contains 'color:#41a200' and Col3 is not null", 0)), "\+(.+?)\<")
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Sorry no, like I said in the post I can get that figure by simply using: =IMPORTXML(J1,"//*[@id='afd-header-views-30d']"). ___

I'm after the figures contained within the bottom line graph for monthly view difference, I want to get at all the changes in months previously (july, june, april, etc.).
 ___ 
It is interesting what you've done with the code, and could maybe use the daily figures in the second column if you have a formula for that too. Appreciate your help!

Comment: you mean these numbers? `=QUERY(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(IMPORTDATA(
 "https://socialblade.com/youtube/user/ryoya1983/monthly"), 5000, 3), 
 "where Col1 contains 'color:#41a200'", 0)`